# How do I keep cells blank until reference data is completed?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

In cell U1 I am using   =IF(T1>0,"P","L").   This works fine.

My issue is it is filling in all the cells down the column. Most of these cells do not have any data (but they do have other formulas) in the preceeding cell ie T2, T3, T4 etc have not been completed but my column U with the above formula is showing it all as L as it is following the formula above which is correct.

How do I have the cells in Column U remain clear until a result appears in the cells in Column T?

Column T Column U

```
1        P

        L
```

Answer (score 0):

use a simple formula in U2:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(if(T2:T="","",if(T2:T>1,"P","L")))`

[image]